# How to set each row in datagrid with a different color

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, resources

I have a log window with a datagrid, each entry write to new row in the datagrid.

I want to set the row color accordingly to the severity of the log message (e.g. fatal exception = Red , Information = Green).

How do i can do it with binding or dynamic resource?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that this is not for Silverlight, you can use DataTriggers.

Assume `Severity` is exposed as a property from your items...

```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type toolkit:DataGridRow}">
         <Style.Triggers>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Severity}" Value="High">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
             </DataTrigger> 
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Severity}" Value="Medium">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
             </DataTrigger> 
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Severity}" Value="Low">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
             </DataTrigger> 
         </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
```

For silverlight you should use converters...

```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type toolkit:DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="{Binding Path=Severity,
                                Converter={StaticResource StatusToColorConveter}}"/>
   </Style>
```

In StatusToColorConveter.Convert() method ...

```
  switch(value.toString())
  {
      case "High": return Colors.Red;
      case "Medium": return Colors.Yellow;
      case "Low": return Colors.Green;
  }
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: `"you will have to use DataTriggers"`, that is not correct as there are various other ways, including the ValueConverters you mentioned yourself. I would recommend you stay away from such strong statements unless you can be sure that the solution set is indeed bounded (and in this case (`"will have to"`) contains only one element).